# children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter

```
return Card(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Placeholder(
        fallbackHeight: 100,
        fallbackWidth: 100,
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 10,  child: Container(child: Text("One"),)),
          Expanded(child: Container(child:  Text("Center") )),

        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

On the code above I am getting error:

> I/flutter ( 4872): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   I/flutter ( 4872): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
>   I/flutter ( 4872): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
>   I/flutter ( 4872): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
>   I/flutter ( 4872): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
>   I/flutter ( 4872): space in the vertical direction.

Whole code:

```
class FilmItems extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> filmListList;

  List<String> _getFilmList() {
    var items = List<String>.generate(101, (counter) => "item $counter");
    return items;
  }

  FilmItems() {
    filmListList = _getFilmList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: filmListList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Placeholder(
                  fallbackHeight: 100,
                  fallbackWidth: 100,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: 10,  child: Container(child: Text("One"),)),
                    Expanded(child: Container(child:  Text("Center") )),

                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This code seems to work fine, where are you returning this? Could you post the parent widgets that have this Card?

Comment: @Pablo I have added more code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Expanded` and any of it's parents have an explicit height.

The solution would depend on how do you want to handle the height of the `Expanded`. In your case, seems to be that you want to have a `Row` with a fixed height equal to the `Placeholder`. In that case, you need to wrap the `Row` with the same height as the `Placeholder`, like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("")),
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Placeholder(
                    fallbackHeight: 100,
                    fallbackWidth: 100,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("One"),
                      Expanded(child: Center(child: Text("Center"))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
  );
}
```

I removed the height `10` of the `Text("One")` because if the `fontSize` is bigger, the text would look cropped. And I wrapped the `Text("Center")` with a `Center` widget, I think that's what you wanted to achieve.

**Suggestion:** If the content inside the `Row` could haven a bigger height than the `Row`, the content would look cropped. If that could happen you might want to take another approach.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using Column widget, it's parent should have a finite height. So in your code the parent is a row and it also does not have a finite height. You need wrap Column with Container and give a finite height.

```
Container(
     height: 500,
     child: Column()
)
```

Comment: so Row do not have explicit height?

Comment: No.. Only if the children have a finite height. In your example you have use expanded inside Coloumn. So the column will try to expand to its max possible height. But since Column's parent also doesn't have a finite height, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Column/Row inside an Expanded or SizedBox (with some height) like this:

```js
Expanded(
  child: Column(...)
)
```

Or

```js
SizedBox(
  height: 250, // give some height
  child: Column(...),
)
```